# java execute hook code before method return

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I would like to have a post hook that is run before a method return. It should be possible add a hook to any method without modifying existing code. Is there a tool or technology that helps realise this? Is javassist a candidate here? If yes, how to pass parameters to the hook? Ideally whatever the method returns should be passed as parameter to the hook.

Comment: You might want to look at aspectj for this: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the technique is called byte code engineering. There are several popular tools. The most famous higher level tool is called AspectJ.

However there are lower level tools like CGLIB, Javassiste, BCEL.

Comment: This answers the question. Thank you. After evaluation, we decided go with a custom hook framework based on a couple of factors: 1) possibility to pass arbitrary hook parameters, 2) possibility to add hooks at arbitrary points, 3) the client code from where hooks are triggered is also under development - so it is possible to add hooks by modifying the code. The hook framework is being design in such a way that it can be extended later with aspects/javaassist to introduce hooks without modifying client code.

Comment: Take a look on aspectj before.  It is very strong an hopefully will satisfy all your requirements.